# how to integrate tabby payment gateway in laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

Can anyone guide me on How to integrate tabby-payment-gateway in larval? session creation
This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

Answer (score 0):

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veXUli3rsHo) may help you

The required fields are:

```
payment: {
    amount , currency , description
    buyer: {phone , email , name}
    shipping_address: {city , address , zip}
    order: {tax_amount , shipping_amount , discount_amount , updated_at , reference_id , items}
    buyer_history: {registered_since , loyalty_level}
    order_history

},
lang
merchant_code
merchant_urls: {success,cancel,failure},
create_token
```